# How to compute Riemann curvature operator $R(v,w) = [\nabla_v, \nabla_w] - \nabla_{[v,w]}$ from explicit transport?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I am reading the book "Functional Differential Geometry" by Sussman, Wisdom and Farr. And i stuck with derivation of Riemann curvature operator from explicit transport in the section 8.1. I have got the line of reasoning till the equation 8.10: how differential equations are derived, how evolution operators is defined as Taylor series for differential operators $L_{g}$, and how they are composed. [The book](https://tile.loc.gov/storage-services/master/gdc/gdcebookspublic/20/22/66/74/82/2022667482/2022667482.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A418%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Fit%22%7D%5D) is available from the LoC, so excuse me for not reproducing all the formulas.

Then comes the second part of the equation 8.10:

$(e^{\epsilon L_{g_w}} e^{\epsilon L_{g_v}} e^{-\epsilon L_{g_w}} e^{-\epsilon L_{g_v}} I)(s_0) = (e^{\epsilon^2[L_{g_w}, L_{g_v}]+\dots}I)(s_0)$

I do not understand, why the exponentiation is here. If i manually expand the series i get directly something like $\left((\epsilon^2[L_{g_w}, L_{g_v}]+\dots)I\right)(s_0)$ on the right hand side. Am i wrong? What i do not get here?

Then from Wikipedia article on [Riemann Curvature Tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Formally) i've got why we interested only in second order term: other will just vanish after taking second derivative at $\epsilon = 0$. So the first term of Riemann operator is more or less clear to me. But where the second term $-\nabla_{[v,w]}$ does come from?

I have tried to read other books, but i found only explanations in coordinate terms, so there is no $-\nabla_{[v,w]}$ also. Then i have tried to take the derivative from Wikipedia article, and failed: i've got commutator of nablas, but not the nabla of the commutator.

Maybe anyone will suggest further readings or will give some directions for reasoning? I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When $\varepsilon \to 0$, you should obtain $s_0 = s_0$, but your own computations lead to $s_0 = 0$.

Comment: @Didier we should not take $\epsilon\to 0$ we take second derivative by $\epsilon$ at 0.